# Creating a scatter plot for multiple rows in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, lattice, scatter-plot

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
        Samp1    Samp2    Samp3     Samp4    Samp5
Gene1    84.1     45.2     34.3      54.6     76.2
Gene2    94.2     12.4     68.0      75.3     24.8
Gene3    29.5     10.5     43.2      39.5     45.5
...
```

I am trying to create a scatter plot where the x-axis are the samples(Samp1-5), and the y-axis are the rows(Gene1-3 and so on), but I want the data of each row to be plotted as a different color on the same plot.

Any thoughts on how to do this in R?  I am more than willing to use ggplot2, lattice, car or any other package in R.

Comment: FYI: When you happen to get an answer that solves your problem, it's very helpful for the site as a whole if you click the little check mark next to the answer that solved your problem. That way future readers know for sure that that answer solved your problem. (But of course, you should only do this if the answer really did solve your problem.)

Comment: OK Thanks @joran.  Will do - Although I have yet to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `ggplot2`:

The data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="Samp1    Samp2    Samp3     Samp4    Samp5
  Gene1    84.1     45.2     34.3      54.6     76.2
  Gene2    94.2     12.4     68.0      75.3     24.8
  Gene3    29.5     10.5     43.2      39.5     45.5", header = TRUE)
```

The plot:

```
library(ggplot2)  
ggplot(stack(dat), aes(x = ind, y = values, colour = rownames(dat))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, why am I getting this error when I'm trying to reproduce your example? Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:rownames(dat)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in lattice or ggplot2 then you will probably need to reshape your data to long format, see the `reshape` function or the `reshape2` package.

For base graphics the `matplot` function will probably do what you want, you may need to supress the x-axis and use the `axis` function to add your own if you don't want just the numbers 1 through 5 as the axis tick marks.

Answer (score 0):

Put the data into a matrix:

```
foo <- as.matrix(structure(list(Samp1 = c(84.1, 94.2, 29.5),
    Samp2 = c(45.2, 12.4, 10.5),Samp3 = c(34.3, 68, 43.2),
    Samp4 = c(54.6, 75.3, 39.5),Samp5 = c(76.2, 24.8, 45.5)),
  .Names = c("Samp1", "Samp2","Samp3", "Samp4", "Samp5"),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Gene1","Gene2", "Gene3")))
```

And plot:

```
plot(seq(1,ncol(foo)),foo[1,],xlab="",ylab="",xaxt="n",
  pch=21,bg=1,ylim=c(min(foo),max(foo)))
axis(side=1,at=seq(1,ncol(foo)),labels=colnames(foo))
for ( ii in 2:nrow(foo) ) points(seq(1,ncol(foo)),foo[ii,],pch=21,col=ii,bg=ii)
```

Note that I am cycling through colors by their numbers (`col=ii,bg=ii`). See `?palette`.

You may also want to look at `?legend`.

[image: scatterplot]

Answer (score 0):

after the introduction of the tidyverse the recommended way is to use tidyr to transform the data into long form. E.g.

```
dat <- read.table(text="Gene Samp1    Samp2    Samp3     Samp4    Samp5
  Gene1    84.1     45.2     34.3      54.6     76.2
  Gene2    94.2     12.4     68.0      75.3     24.8
  Gene3    29.5     10.5     43.2      39.5     45.5", header = TRUE)

dat %>% 
  # transform data to long form
  tidyr::gather("sample", "value", contains("Samp")) %>%
  # plot the data
  ggplot(aes(x = sample, y = value, col = Gene)) + geom_point()
```